# Laravel relationships in migrations?

Tags: database, migration, relationship, laravel

I know you can define table relationships fairly easy with `$this->belongs_to()`, `$this->has_many()` etc, but what i don't understand is how the relationship table is created; the table that binds the two tables together (i forgot what the term is called).

Let's say i'm creating a users table. I want that user to belong to a certain "Role". There are multiple roles, and every role can have multiple users. I will need to also create a `roles` table for that. So far, so good.

But after reading the documentation, it says i should add the `$this->belongs_to()` in the model, not the migration itself. When, and how is the relationship table created? If i create the `roles` and `users` tables, and add `$this->belongs_to('roles')` to the `users` model, and `$this->has_many('users')` to the `roles` model, will the middle table be created automatically?

Comment: Regarding "i forgot what the term is called", these tables are commonly called Pivot Tables, Intermediate Tables or Lookup Tables depending on which DB background you're from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no relationship table will be created. What you will need to do is have a `role_id` on your `users` table, so that when you create a user, the ID of the role will be stored there. This will enable you do select all users where `role_id == '1'` or whatever it may be. 
For example:

```
$admins = User::where('role_id', '=', 1);
```

Where on the `ROLES` table the record with `ID='1'` is admin.
So again to answer your question, no relationship table is created, instead the relationship exists within your two tables in the form of a `role_id` column for each user. Out of interest, are you using foreign keys?

If you want to have a relationships table you could create one called `user_roles` or something and store the `role_id` and `user_id` in there, however I think its easier to use the above method as then you can use all the Laravel/Eloquent goodness.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I figured out that no relationship table is needed if i only store one role per user. But what if every user could have unlimited roles? Then i have no other choice than to store it in another table, right? How would that work? I know Laravel can create and manage these tables automatically for you, but i don't how how, where or when it does it.

Comment: So which is better, whether to create relations on database itself by changing migration files or just defining relationships in model files?
or using both techniques

Answer (score 83):

When creating a migration you can specify foreign keys on your tables,
i.e.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('roles', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        //rest of fields then...
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

This will create a foreign key on the user_id column on the roles table.
The benefits of foreign keys is that when an update or delete is made the foreign key table will be automatically updated or "cascaded" great description found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/)

As described on the Laravel documentation you could also specify your cascading on update using the following syntax

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')->on('users')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

I would do a bad job of trying to explain it better than the documentation does so please have a read through the ["Relationships"](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) section of the Eloquent ORM documentation to see how its done.

Comment: @Roark you probably should have mentioned that the column "user_id" should be created first.. otherwise you'll get an error like: ```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "lang_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist (SQL: alter table "op_cities" add constraint "op_cities_lang_i
  d_foreign" foreign key ("lang_id") references "translator_languages" ("id"))
```

Comment: example of that here: https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/adding-foreign-key-references-using-a-laravel-migration/

Comment: @abbood Updated answer to show more detailed migration example

Comment: Why does it always happened to me that only $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); works?

Comment: @james check this article out. If you’re on Laravel 5.8 it could be the reason: https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/

Comment: A shorter way of creating a foreign ID colum is `$table->foreignIdFor(User::class);`. You can give the column name as the second argument if you want something else than the default.

Answer (score 22):

It looks like a few of the initial questions were never answered, i.e. "When, and how is the relationship table created" & "will the middle table be created automatically":

As far as I am aware, these tables need to be created manually. So create the migration file like so:

*Laravel 5*

```
php artisan make:migration create_role_user_table
```

*Laravel 4*

```
php artisan migrate:make create_role_user_table
```

Note that the names are singular, and are presented in alphabetical order.

Then in the migration something like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Hope that helps. I'm not sure if the timestamps are needed in Pivot Tables or not, so please experiment.

Comment: `migrate:make` is not in artisan for Laravel 5.4, it's `php artisan make:migration`

Comment: where are the relations?

Comment: Dear @mere-development, the question the same as me were looking for the way the relation is made in Laravel in migration time. but all you have described was how to make a table. This line: $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); was the whole point.

Answer (score 14):

Though its an old Post, I though I can contribute something updated. For Laravel5, **Jeffrey Way** has developed a package **[Laravel5 Generators-extended](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended)** which enhance the generator capability of `php artisan` for

- `make:migration:schema`
- `make:migration:pivot`
- `make:seed`

For many-to-many relation between users and role, you can just use

```
php artisan make:migration:pivot users role
```

and it will generate the required migration class. You don't need to code manually for this.

Answer (score 1):

This video helped me.

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14

What was surprising for me was that only one side of the relationship needs pointer_id in migration table, not both. For example, if we have Author with many Articles, we only add

```
$table->integer('author_id')
```

to article migration and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but as I had the same question in mind. I've found the solution in the [Laravel manual (5.0)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) where it is described that for this particular many-to-many relationship you can create the table manually and then declare the type of relationship into Model in this way:

```
return $this -> belongsToMany('App\<Model>', '<table_created_manually>');
```

or if you want to use specific associated keys:

```
return $this -> belongsToMany('App\<Model>', '<rel_table1_table2>' '<table1>_id', '<table2>_id');
```

Hope this can help.